# Fetching string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a txt file (test.txt) with multiple rows

```
2019-12-20 12:00:00: Polling done in Jharkhand with process id:1577103128027
Result
{BJP:"29",
JMM:29",
Congress:12,
Others:11
}
Status:Done
The result is declared under process id:1625616161
```

Objective:-
I would like to fetch data like

Polling done in Jharkhand with process id:
BJP:
Congress:
JMM:

Using Javascript, 
I was trying to search a string "Polling done in Jharkhand with process id:" but it returns null as it doesn't read all rows.

2) I am thing of concatenating all rows into One row and then search a string but unable to do it.

Is there a way to concatenate all rows into One? or is there a way to achieve what i am trying to in Javascript? Please help

Thanks,
sunny

Comment: share the code you have tried so far, [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'd suggest you to store the data using an established data format, like JSON.

Comment: Thanks. The file contains both. Json data as well as text. I need to fetch both. If I can get rows into one row then I can search i think.

Comment: Have tried any code so far, you should try do some work on your own first. i will give u a head start. try the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried any code so far, you should try do some work on your own first. i will give u a head start. try the answer below.

```
   <script>
        $(function(){
            $.get('text.txt', function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                var TextLine = "";
                var rowsArray = data.split('\n')
                console.log(rowsArray)
                jQuery.each(rowsArray, function(i, val) {
                    TextLine += val + "<br />";
                });
                $('body').html(TextLine);
            }, 'text');
        });
    </script>
```

*//console log*

```
(9) […]
0: "2019-12-20 12:00:00: Polling done in Jharkhand with process id:1577103128027\r"
1: "Result\r"
2: "{BJP:\"29\",\r"
3: "JMM:29\",\r"
4: "Congress:12,\r"
5: "Others:11\r"
6: "}\r"
7: "Status:Done\r"
8: "The result is declared under process id:1625616161"
length: 9
```

with this code u can get each line in a array, just call rowsArray[rownumber].
now try out what u want with this.